# Set A Watch: Is Goblin Chief a Goblin?

Tags: untagged

The location I was in was the Goblin Cave, which states:

> Increase the health of **all goblins** by 3

Now, `Goblin` is a creature type that's noted on the bottom of the creature cards. I revealed a *Summon* in the Line, and the *Unhallowed* that came into play here was the `Goblin Chief`. The type box of the `Goblin Chief` states `Unhallowed`, not `Goblin`.

Should I assume it is also a `Goblin` for the *Location*'s ability and increase its health?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the creator, Mike Gnade, [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Pims_pappadag/status/1354443348522708995). His response was:

> Goblin chief? No he’s an unhallowed.

`Goblin Cave` therefor does not boost `Goblin Chief`.